# String_agg equivalent function in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to rewrite my SQL query with stuff or other option available instead of string_agg function as my SQL server doesn't support it.
Can anyone please help me with this?

```
select String_agg(air.code,',') AS Code,String_agg(air.Id,',') AS AId,res.ResId
from  Table1 air
inner join
Table2 rmap on air.Id=airmap.Id
inner join Table3 res on rmap.ResId=res.ResId
group by res.ResId
```

with output like below [image]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also, the functionality is not `stuff()`, which is a simple string function.  The functionality is `for xml path`.

Comment: `STUFF` doesn't aggregate anything, it only removes the leading separator. It's `FOR XML` that aggregates the values as XML whose element names are empty

Comment: `STRING_AGG` is available as of SQL Server 2017. If you have an older version, you may want to consider an upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select res.ResId, 
       stuff( (select ',' + air.code
               from table1 air inner join
                    Table2 rmap
                    on air.Id = airmap.Id
               where rmap.ResId = res.ResId
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, '') as codes,
       stuff( (select ',' + air.aid
               from table1 air inner join
                    Table2 rmap
                    on air.Id = airmap.Id
               where rmap.ResId = res.ResId
               for xml path ('')
              ), 1, 1, '') as aids
from Table3 res ;
```

Comment: At times like that, SQLCLR looks like a far better option. Or upgrading to a recent SQL Server version